# Eigen c++ cast double to long int?

Tags: c++, eigen

Quick question:

consider this (wrong) casting from a double to a long int:

```
Eigen::VectorXd Price      = Map<VectorXd>(price, n);
double TickFactor          = 1.0 / TickSize;
Eigen::VectorXi IntPrice   = (Price * TickFactor).cast <long int> ();
```

which gives the following error (Eigen 3.3.5, g++ 7.3.0):

```
eigen/Eigen/src/Core/util/StaticAssert.h:33:40: error: static assertion failed: YOU_MIXED_DIFFERENT_NUMERIC_TYPES__YOU_NEED_TO_USE_THE_CAST_METHOD_OF_MATRIXBASE_TO_CAST_NUMERIC_TYPES_EXPLICITLY
     #define EIGEN_STATIC_ASSERT(X,MSG) static_assert(X,#MSG);
```

Now, this compiles:

```
Eigen::VectorXi IntPrice   = (Price * TickFactor).cast <int> ();
```

here is my question. Does the line above allows for values of `(Price * TickFactor)` that are larger than the upper limit on a `short int`? --whatever that is on the current system, say 33K.

Comment: Have you tried it? Yes, it should, but why don't you make `33000.` and then no need for a cast?

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher: 'but why don't you make 33000. and then no need for a cast?' I am not sure I understand. Can you elaborate a bit. Thanks!

Comment: If you just say `(Price * TickFactor) > 33000.`, (to have a double value), then there should not be a need for a cast. The code would compile without it (and be more precise)

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher: then my question was not formulated clearly. I edited it.

Comment: The limitations are the same as a usual double -> int cast. So, if you use `int64_t` you would have the full `int64_t` range for your cast (above or lower would have the usual overflow/underflow behavior).

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher: replacing `int` by `int64_t` yields: `eigen/Eigen/src/Core/util/StaticAssert.h:33:40: error: static assertion failed: YOU_MIXED_DIFFERENT_NUMERIC_TYPES__YOU_NEED_TO_USE_THE_CAST_METHOD_OF_MATRIXBASE_TO_CAST_NUMERIC_TYPES_EXPLICITLY
     #define EIGEN_STATIC_ASSERT(X,MSG) static_assert(X,#MSG);`

Comment: You need to store them as `int64_t` by replacing `VectorXi` by a typedef to `Matrix<int64_t,Dynamic,1>`.

Comment: The cast in the first snippet is perfectly fine. You just can't assign the result to a `VectorXi`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line

```
Eigen::VectorXi IntPrice   = (Price * TickFactor).cast <int> ();
```

is essentially equivalent to

```
Eigen::VectorXi IntPrice(Price.size());
for(Eigen::Index i=0; i<Price.size(); ++i)
    IntPrice[i] = static_cast<int>(Price[i] * TickFactor;
```

Unless on your system `short int` and `int` are the same, you are limited to the size of `int` (not `short int`), and the behavior for overflows is (I think) undefined.

If you want 64bit integers, do as ggael suggested:

```
typedef Eigen::Matrix<int64_t,Dynamic,1> VectorXi64;

VectorXi64 IntPrice = (Price * TickFactor).cast<int64_t>();
```